# Set max-height to each element's scrollHeight

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a vertical nested accordion and have a problem using `max-height` property. I'd like to set `max-height` to each `.panel-nested` element's `scrollHeight`. Currently, it's set to the first `.panel-nested` element's `scrollHeight` and from its `max-height`, every element has the same, instead of each element's `max-height`. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/hg5rmhv2/4/

```js
var acc = $('.accordion'),
  accNestedParent = $('.accordion-nested-parent'),
  accNestedHeader = $('.accordion-nested-header');

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $('.accordion').removeClass('active');
      $('.accordion-header').removeClass('active');
      $('.panel').removeClass('active');
      $('.panel').css('max-height', '');
      $(this).next().next().removeClass("top-border");
    } else {
      $('.accordion').removeClass('active');
      $('.accordion-header').removeClass('active');
      $('.panel').removeClass('active');
      $('.panel').css('max-height', '');
      $(this).next().next().removeClass("top-border");

      var accPanel = this.nextElementSibling;
      var nextAcc = this.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling;

      $(this).addClass("active");
      $(this).next().addClass('active');
      $(this).next().next().addClass("top-border");
      if (accPanel.style.maxHeight) {
        accPanel.style.maxHeight = null;
      } else {
        accPanel.style.maxHeight = accPanel.scrollHeight + "px";
      }
    }
  }
}

for (i = 0; i < accNestedParent.length; i++) {
  accNestedParent[i].onclick = function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $('.accordion').removeClass('active');
      $('.accordion-header').removeClass('active');
      $('.accordion-nested-parent').removeClass('active');
      $('.panel').removeClass('active');
      $('.panel-nested-parent').removeClass('active');
      $('.panel').css('max-height', '');
      $('.panel-nested-parent').css('max-height', '');
      $(this).next().next().removeClass("top-border");
    } else {
      $('.accordion').removeClass('active');
      $('.accordion-header').removeClass('active');
      $('.accordion-nested-parent').removeClass('active');
      $('.panel, .panel-nested-parent').removeClass('active');
      $('.panel, .panel-nested-parent').css('max-height', '');
      $(this).next().next().removeClass("top-border");

      var $accNestedParent = $('.panel-nested-parent');
      var totalHeight = $('.panel-nested-parent')[0].scrollHeight;

      $(this).addClass('active');

      $('.panel-nested-parent').each(function() {
        if ($(this).css('max-height') == true) {
          $(this).css('max-height', '');
        } else {
          $(this).css('max-height', totalHeight + 'px');
        }
      });
    }
  }
}

for (i = 0; i < accNestedHeader.length; i++) {
  accNestedHeader[i].onclick = function() {
    if ($(this).find('.accordion-nested').hasClass('active')) {
      $('.panel').removeClass('active');
      $('.panel').css('max-height', '');
      $('.panel-nested').removeClass('active');
      $('.panel-nested').css('max-height', '');
      $('.accordion').removeClass('active');
      $('.accordion-header').removeClass('active');
      $('.accordion-nested').removeClass('active');
      $(this).next().next().removeClass("top-border");
    } else {
      $('.panel').removeClass('active');
      $('.panel').css('max-height', '');
      $('.panel-nested').removeClass('active');
      $('.panel-nested').css('max-height', '');
      $('.accordion').removeClass('active');
      $('.accordion-header').removeClass('active');
      $('.accordion-nested').removeClass('active');
      $(this).next().next().removeClass("top-border");

      var accPanel = $(this).find('.panel-nested');

      $(this).find('.accordion-nested').addClass('active');
      $(this).find('.panel-nested').addClass('active');
      $(this).find('.accordion-nested').addClass("top-border");

      if (accPanel.css('max-height') == true) {
        accPanel.css('max-height', '');
      } else {
        var a = $('.panel-nested')[0].scrollHeight + $('.panel-nested-parent')[0].scrollHeight;
        $('.panel-nested-parent').css('max-height', a);
        /***********************************************************/
        accPanel.css('max-height', $('.panel-nested')[0].scrollHeight);
        /************************************************************/

      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div.accordion-header {
  border: 1px solid #1e5d86;
  background: #f7ba01;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 4px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.accordion,
.accordion-nested,
.accordion-nested-parent {
  border: 1px solid #1e5d86;
  border-top: none;
  background: #21aedb;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

.accordion.active,
.accordion-nested.active,
.accordion-nested:hover,
.accordion-nested-parent.active,
.accordion-nested-parent:hover,
.accordion:hover {
  background: #0E82A7;
}

.accordion:after,
.accordion-nested:after,
.accordion-nested-parent:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
}

button.accordion.active,
.accordion-nested.active,
.accordion-nested-parent.active {
  border-bottom: none;
}

button.accordion.active:after,
.accordion-nested.active:after,
.accordion-nested-parent.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

button.accordion.top-border,
.accordion-nested.top-border,
.accordion-nested-parent.top-border {
  border-top: 1px solid #1e5d86;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.panel,
.panel-nested,
.panel-nested-parent {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height .4s ease-out;
  transition: max-height .4s ease-out;
}

div.panel.active {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.accordion-nested-header:hover button {
  background: #0E82A7;
}

.panel-nested-parent:nth-child(even) tr {
  border-top: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #f7ba01;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid #1e5d86;
}

td {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 2px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #21aedb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="accordion-nested-parent">Kaimynai (nauja v)</button>
<div class="panel-nested-parent">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Pelnas nuo įsigytų</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr class="accordion-nested-header" style="border: none;">
      <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0;">
        <button style="border-right: none;" class="accordion-nested">Gyvulių (5%)</button>
        <div class="panel-nested">
          <table>
            <tr style="border-right: none;">
              <th style="background: #21aedb;">Gyvulys</th>
              <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">Kiekis</th>
              <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">Pelnas (Eur)</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Gyvulys</td>
              <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 vnt.</td>
              <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 Eur</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Gyvulys</td>
              <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 vnt.</td>
              <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 Eur</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Gyvulys</td>
              <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 vnt.</td>
              <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 Eur</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Gyvulys</td>
              <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 vnt.</td>
              <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 Eur</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Gyvulys</td>
              <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 vnt.</td>
              <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 Eur</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Gyvulys</td>
              <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 vnt.</td>
              <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 Eur</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0;">
          <button style="border-right: none;" class="accordion-nested">Fermų (10%)</button>
          <div class="panel-nested">
            <table>
              <tr style="border-right: none;">
                <th style="background: #21aedb;">Ferma</th>
                <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1; ">Kiekis</th>
                <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1; ">Pelnas (Eur)</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Gyvulys</td>
                <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 vnt.</td>
                <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 Eur</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Gyvulys</td>
                <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 vnt.</td>
                <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 Eur</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Gyvulys</td>
                <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 vnt.</td>
                <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 Eur</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Gyvulys</td>
                <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 vnt.</td>
                <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 Eur</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Gyvulys</td>
                <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 vnt.</td>
                <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 Eur</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Gyvulys</td>
                <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 vnt.</td>
                <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 Eur</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Gyvulys</td>
                <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 vnt.</td>
                <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 Eur</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Gyvulys</td>
                <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 vnt.</td>
                <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 Eur</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Gyvulys</td>
                <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 vnt.</td>
                <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 Eur</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Gyvulys</td>
                <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 vnt.</td>
                <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 Eur</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Gyvulys</td>
                <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 vnt.</td>
                <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 Eur</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Gyvulys</td>
                <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 vnt.</td>
                <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 Eur</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0; ">
            <button style="border-right: none; " class="accordion-nested ">Fabrikų (10%)</button>
            <div class="panel-nested ">
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <th style="background: #21aedb; ">Fabrikas</th>
                  <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1; ">Kiekis</th>
                  <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1; ">Pelnas</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Fabrikai</td>
                  <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1; ">1 vnt.</td>
                  <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1; ">1 Eur</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0; ">
            <button class="accordion-nested ">Kepyklų (10%)</button>
            <div class="panel-nested ">
              <table>
                <tr style="border-left: none; ">
                  <th style="background: #21aedb; ">Kepykla</th>
                  <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1; ">Kiekis</th>
                  <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1; ">Pelnas</th>
                </tr>
                <tr style="border-left: none; ">
                  <td>Kepyklos</td>
                  <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1; ">1 vnt.</td>
                  <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1; ">1 Eur</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="panel-nested-parent">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Pelnas nuo įsigytų</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr class="accordion-nested-header" style="border: none;">
      <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0;">
        <button style="border-right: none;" class="accordion-nested">Gyvulių (5%)</button>
        <div class="panel-nested">
          <table>
            <tr style="border-right: none;">
              <th style="background: #21aedb;">Gyvulys</th>
              <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">Kiekis</th>
              <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">Pelnas (Eur)</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Gyvulys</td>
              <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 vnt.</td>
              <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1;">0 Eur</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0;">
          <button style="border-right: none;" class="accordion-nested">Fermų (10%)</button>
          <div class="panel-nested">
            <table>
              <tr style="border-right: none;">
                <th style="background: #21aedb;">Ferma</th>
                <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1; ">Kiekis</th>
                <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1; ">Pelnas (Eur)</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Fermos</td>
                <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1; ">1 vnt.</td>
                <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1; ">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0; ">
            <button style="border-right: none; " class="accordion-nested ">Fabrikų (10%)</button>
            <div class="panel-nested ">
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <th style="background: #21aedb; ">Fabrikas</th>
                  <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1; ">Kiekis</th>
                  <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1; ">Pelnas</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Fabrikai</td>
                  <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1; ">1 vnt.</td>
                  <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1; ">1 Eur</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0; ">
            <button class="accordion-nested ">Kepyklų (10%)</button>
            <div class="panel-nested ">
              <table>
                <tr style="border-left: none; ">
                  <th style="background: #21aedb; ">Kepykla</th>
                  <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1; ">Kiekis</th>
                  <th style="background: #21aedb; border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1; ">Pelnas</th>
                </tr>
                <tr style="border-left: none; ">
                  <td>Kepyklos</td>
                  <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1; ">1 vnt.</td>
                  <td style="border-left: 1px solid #1f76a1; ">1 Eur</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Take a look at this line:

`accPanel.css('max-height', $('.panel-nested')[0].scrollHeight);`

As you can see, it sets the `accPanel max-height` to the first `.panel-nested` element's `scrollHeight` and the same rule applies to the every `.panel-nested` element. The `max-height` should be different in the every element, according to its `scrollHeight`. Is it possible to do so using a jQuery `$.each()` function? You can see why I can't use `accPanel.css('max-height', $('.panel-nested')[0].scrollHeight);`:
[image]

The second `.panel-nested` uses first `.panel-nested` element's `max-height`, so it doesn't show full second `.panel-nested` content. The same thing can happen to the every `.panel-nested` element, except the first one in the first `.panel-nested-parent` element. So, I have to do two things to make everything work correctly:

1. Set `max-height` to the each `.panel-nested` element's `scrollHeight`.
2. Set `max-height` to the each `.panel-nested-parent` element's `scrollHeight`.